# What's the proper way to implement a "static" authorization token feature using OIDC (or OAuth2)

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, authorization, openid-connect

I am exploring possible solutions for creating something like "API Keys" to consume my API. The goal is to allow for users to generate one or many "API Keys" from the web app and use the static generated key from the CLI app.

The web app and the client app are already using standard OIDC with JWT tokens for authentication and authorization using RBAC (role-based access control). The CLI app can already authenticate the user through the standard browser flow (redirects the user to the browser to authenticate and exchange the token back to the client).

The "API Keys" solution I am trying to achieve should have some fine-grained options where it won't authenticate as the user, but will authorize the client on behalf of the user (something like the GitHub Personal Access Token).

To me it seems like a "solved problem" as multiple services provide this kind of feature and my goal is to do it the most standard way possible using the Oauth2/OIDC protocols but I can't find details on what parts of the protocols should be used.

Can anybody provide any guidance on how it is supposed to be done using the Oauth2/OIDC entities?

Can I achieve it by only using Role-based access control or do I need Resource-based access control?

It went through the path of creating a new client for each "API Key" created, but it didn't feel right to create so many clients in the realm.

Any guidance or links to any materials are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anybody provide any guidance on how it is supposed to be done
> using the Oauth2/OIDC entities?

OIDC is based on OAUth 2.0 so after user login you have id tokens, access token and refresh token on the backend side. To generate new access token without asking user for authentication data you should use refresh token: https://oauth.net/2/refresh-tokens/

> Can I achieve it by only using Role-based access control or do I need
> Resource-based access control?

resource-based access control is more flexible solution here, but if you business requirement is not complex, then role based might be enough.

> It went through the path of creating a new client for each "API Key"
> created, but it didn't feel right to create so many clients in the
> realm.

It is one application so you should use one client with specific configuration for access token and roles/permissions for users.

Update:
We can use GitHub as an example:

1. User is authenticated during login

- for OIDC code is exchanged for id token, access token and refresh token
- session for user is set for web browser

2. User can request access token

- in GitHub authenticated user can request github.com/settings/personal-access-tokens/new endpoint
- request is accepted, because user is authenticated based on session
- backend service responsible for returning access token can obtain new access token using refresh token from point 1.
- access token is returned to GitHub user

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just checking if I understand, you suggesting that I expose the refresh token to the user as the "API KEY" and use it every time to get the access token. When I generate the token the first time I select the scopes that I want and those scopes will provide the roles I want with that token?

Comment: No, you should not store refresh token on frontend.  During OIDC flow, backend client exchange code for token response that contains id token, access token and refresh token. Based on id token user session is created and with session id you can authenticate user, and if the user needs new access token that you want to return to use as api key, then you can send request to your application and application will use refresh token to get new access token that you can return as API key to the user.

Comment: You can check how it is done on the GitHub: 1. User login and is authenticated - session is created 2. With valid session user can send request to  https://github.com/settings/personal-access-tokens/new for new access token 3. because you are using some authorisation server, then access token should be obtained based on refresh token returned during user login.

Comment: Okay, so, the OIDC flow is already implemented on my web app and on the CLI app (cli uses offline sessions). In both cases the clients will exchange the token on behalf of the user after redirection so we only use the access token on requests to my API and it's been working without issues. In both cases the access token is refreshed with the refresh token. What I need now is a non-interactive solution for stateless environments, for instance, depending on the deployment the cli code won't be able to store the session details to refresh the access token next time.

Comment: The access token is what I need to engage with the API but it expires shortly (as it should be because the API doesn't check the session on each request). If I use the access token as API KEY (this is what I already do) it will expire soon and a new authentication will be required. I could "share" the refresh token as "api key" and the CLI can use it to get a new access token and keep the session in memory until next usage where it uses the refresh token again on the setup. But you mentioned I should not share the refresh token and that part is confusing to me.

Comment: Ok, so this approach is not recommended, OAuth 2.0 was not well specified at the beginning and was not designed for user authentication so OIDC was introduced, but to some extent it is accepted, you can check best approaches for web applications here: https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-10.html in general topic is quite complex, but it clears up whole idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251025/discussion-between-mszmc-and-luigibertaco).

Answer (score 0):

To call your API in an OAuth way, CLI users must authenticate periodically. Resulting access tokens can be long lived, as for GitHub keys, if you judge that secure enough. The access token returned can be used exactly like an API key. There may be a little friction here between usability and security.

**CONSOLE FLOW**

The classic flow for a console app is to use the Native Apps Desktop Flow from [RFC8252](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252#section-7.3). This involves the user interactively signing in using the code flow, then receiving the response on a loopback URL. It is an interactive experience, but should only be required occasionally, as for GitHub tokens.

**API KEYS**

The access token returned is sent in the authorization header and you can use it as an API key. Access tokens can use a reference token format. to make them shorter and confidential, to prevent information disclosure. These will be more natural in a CLI.

**API AUTHORIZATION**

When your API is called, it must receive access tokens containing scopes and claims, to identify the user. This will enable you to authorize correctly and lock down permissions.

```json
{
  sub: 586368,
  scope: repos_write,
  topic: mobile,
  subscription_level: silver
  exp: ?
}
```

**TOKEN REFRESH**

Sometimes CLI access tokens are long lived, for convenience. A more secure option is for the CLI to use token refresh. It can then store a refresh token in OS secure storage, then renew access tokens seamlessly. My [blog post](https://authguidance.com/final-desktop-sample-overview/) has some screenshots on how this looks, and a desktop app that does not require login upon restart. The CLI needs to deal with expired access tokens and handle 401 responses.

**DYNAMIC CLIENT REGISTRATION**

Some developer portal scenarios use DCR. It is another option in your security toolbox. It could potentially enable a silent client per CLI user:

- User runs a standard authentication flow with a DCR scope
- This returns an access token that enables client registration
- The resulting token is used to register a new client
- This could potentially be a client ID and client secret used in a CLI

Afterwards, the user and client are bound together. Probably not immediately relevant, but worth knowing about.

Comment: OK, but it means that it won't be on behalf of user, rather on behalf of client which is client credentials grant type, additionally you need new client per user + with OIDC you have same configuration for access token as for user login. I think it is not right, because you want to add mechanism that partly Is based on OAuth, but need some additional client -> user mapping. With OIDC it is just about adding new endpoint that communicate with AS based on refresh token grant type and returns new access token.

Comment: Yeah - you are right - I should be promoting the most standard option. So I updated my answer. I wanted to mention DCR but it is more of an edge case.

Comment: Thank for you detailed answer. I already use the access token as Bearer token for requests to my API as you suggested. The access token is generated using the standard browser flow (console > browser > loopback URL). Comparing with the GitHub Personal Access Token, what I need is a token that allows me to get a new access token for a very long time, so the initial "handshake" can happen without any user interaction until the API Key is expired. Using access tokens for that would only allow usage for a short time or I'd have to increase the lifespan (what is not safe). What am I missing here?

Comment: I updated my answer - have a look at refresh token OS storage - see if that works for you